# Android nougat can't re-enable location after disabling in front panel settings

Tags: android

Hey good day how override front panel settings to re-enable the location or request permission? It only worked the pop-up request permission the first time the app is installed. When you disabled the location using front panel settings and re-run the app the popup permission request does not work. How to solve this?
 [image]

```
 public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION)
                ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are just requesting for the permission to access location. Requesting permission doesn't turn on location. You have to ask the user to turn on GPS.

Comment: is the location a gps settings ? can it be turn on programmatically

Comment: You can not turn on programatically. You need to prompt the user to turn on location. Please go through below link.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings#java